# How to do code coverage test for an ASP.NET WebForms app using Visual Studio 2010? Is Generic Test used?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I want to find out which methods not being executed in the app. I read [this tutorial](http://www.buffington.com/Blog/post/2010/04/27/Visual-Studio-2010-Code-Coverage-Testing-in-10-Easy-Steps.aspx) for doing a code coverage test for an .exe file. I want to do the same for an ASP.NET WebForms app. What I am missing is if I need to create a Generic Test, what is to be entered in the different fields in the screen below, specially the wrapper program in the first field?

I will be clicking around the app to cover as many methods as I can.

**UPDATE:**

I added a winForm project and made its .exe file the wrapper. In the Code Coverage configuration I added the website project as an artifact to instrument (path = http://...). The code coverage results didn't show anything. I also added the web project assembly at one time. After trying different combinations on what artifacts to instrument, the code coverage results either showed nothing or showed results for the .exe only (If I added the winForm project). I also Googled around. I am not sure anymore if VS 2010 can code cover ASP.NET apps without using unit tests.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used VsInstr.exe and VSPerfCmd.exe to accomplish what I needed.